# Normality relation between product of subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I need to solve this exercise for the proof of Dedekind's modular law.
Let $G$ be a group, $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$, $H$ and $K$ subgroups of $G$ with $H$ normal subgroup of $K$.
I want to show that the product $NH$ is a normal subgroup of $NK$.
I know that $NH$ is a group and I started by choosing $nh\in NH, mk \in NK$. I want to prove that $$k^{-1}m^{-1}nhmk\in NH.$$
Defining $g=mk$, I wrote it as
$$(g^{-1}ng)(g^{-1}hg).$$ Now, the first term is in $N$, but I can't prove that the other one is in $H$.

Comment: Hello, welcome. If $H\triangleleft G$, then $g^{-1}hg \in H$.

Comment: But, the hypothesis is only that $H \lhd K$. The normalizer of $H$ might well be a proper subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the map $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ from $NH$ to itself. This is a bijection and hence $NH=HN$. Similar argument shows that $NK=KN$.

Therefore, there will be $x\in K$ and $y\in N$, such that $xy=g$. Then
$$g^{-1}hg =y^{-1}x^{-1}hxy\in y^{-1}Hy.$$
Now since
$$Hy\subset HN=NH,$$
we have
$$g^{-1}hg\in y^{-1}Hy\subset y^{-1}NH=NH.$$